# Can't start thunar as root

Tags: 16.04, gksudo

I have a script with this.

```
gxsudo thunar
```

It no longer works. Did a kernel upgrade delete the program?

Running 16.04 Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: What's `gxsudo`? I have only ever heard of `gksudo`.

Comment: your problem is likely a typo `gksudo` works. If your script ever worked you likely had an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) setting `gxsudo` as an alias of `gksudo`

Answer (score 8):

The command `gxsudo thunar` that you tried to run in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 is incorrect. The correct command in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 is:

```
gksu thunar
```

The gksu package, which provides GTK+ front-ends for su (gksu) and sudo (gksudo), was removed from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories for security reasons, so it won't be available starting with this Ubuntu release.

It is recommended in Ubuntu 18.04 and later to open thunar as root only when it is needed, otherwise use `cd` in the terminal to change directories.

```
sudo -H thunar &>/dev/null
```

Nautilus Admin (*nautilus-admin*) is a simple Python extension for the Nautilus file manager that adds some administrative actions to the right-click menu:

- Open as Administrator: opens a folder in a new Nautilus window running with administrator (root) privileges.
- Edit as Administrator: opens a file in a Gedit window running with administrator (root) privileges.

To install Nautilus Admin in all  currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```

While there are commands to run graphical applications as root, you are strongly advised to use nano text editor, which normally is run from the terminal, for editing files as root. Nano text editor is included in the default Ubuntu installation.

Nano is very easy to use. The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

If you get into the habit of editing files as root the right way, you will reduce the possibility of making mistakes that may be very time consuming to correct.

Comment: What is going to happen if I omitted `&>/dev/null`?

Comment: @aasril If you omitted `&>/dev/null` you would see any warning messages that `&>/dev/null` disables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean `gksudo`.
This package can be reinstalled by issuing the command:

```
$ sudo apt install gksu
```

Based on a cursory google search it would appear that the developers removed it from the default install sometime in 13.04 due to security concerns.

Comment: and `gksu` has now been removed from 18.04  (https://jeremy.bicha.net/2018/04/18/gksu-removed-from-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

`thunar admin://` is I have read the better way.

Comment: Not applicable to 16.04